# Unable to use pair of items within a function when I go for concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to make use of `concurrent.futures` within my script below. There are two functions `make_requests()` and `get_info()` within it. When `make_requests()` function yields `links` and `proxy_list`, I intend to pass them within `get_info()` function.

Usually this is how it works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # "proxy_lists" is the holder of different proxies
    proxies = [proxy_lists]

    # make_requests() function yields "links" and "proxy_list"
    for item,elem in make_requests(url,proxies):

        # pass "links" and "proxy_list" to get_info() function
        get_info(item,elem)
```

I don't find any idea to do the same using `concurrent.futures` as it requires a paired loop to produce two type of elements by this `make_requests()` function and then pass the two type of elements within `get_info()` function like I did above:

```
import concurrent.futures

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxies = [proxy_lists]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_info,link): link for link in make_requests(url,proxies)}
        concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
```

***How can I pass pair of items within `get_info()` function when I use `concurrent.futures`?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to do: `executor.submit(get_info, *link)`

this is because [`Executor.submit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) is documented as:

> `submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> Schedules the callable, fn, to be executed as fn(*args **kwargs)

this uses standard [arbitrary argument handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/1358308) to make sure that everything goes through to `fn`

the `*link` treats `link` as a sequence, unpacking it as arguments to `submit`, which in turn does then same when it eventually invokes `fn`